# Console application vs WCF service application for WCF project in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wcf

I am currently making my first steps into the world of WCF for the past week or so.

And something keeps popping up on my mind regarding when to use a console app or a WCF Service app in Visual Studio 2010?

Is it all about self hosting or IIS and WAS hosting? The way I got it is that if I am self hosting, a console application is the way to go, since that you would implement the `ServiceHost` and proxy yourself, whereas in case of IIS or WAS hosting we use a WCF service application? Where the `ServiceHost` is dynamically generated?

Is my understanding regarding this issue correct? Or there are more things into it? I feel like some link is missing in here...

Comment: The problem with a console app is that it only runs within a users session - there are some fudging ways to run console apps as windows services, but I've never felt it to be the same as creating an actual windows service.

Comment: So hosting in console app is basically for debugging?

Can I self host a WCF Service app for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer this MSDN article for more details on hosting.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx

Comment: Perfect article! I have no idea how I missed it when I was reading about WCF hosting!
Thanks a lot.